# Hazelcast getHeapCost method returns a negative result

Tags: java, hazelcast

**Quick Summary**: Can somebody explain to me what a negative value for getHeapCost as per http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/monitor/LocalMapStats.html#getHeapCost() means?

**Further Details**:

We are using a Hazelcast in a Java enterprise application. We are experiencing intermittent performance issues and are trying to pinpoint the issue (issues?).

As part of the logging we gather some statistics on the Hazelcast map using the provided methods as per http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/monitor/LocalMapStats.html.

One particular result in our logs that stands out to me as being quite odd is getting negative values for the getHeapCost() method. This also seems to be intermittent and somewhat correlates to our performance problems, but I don't know if this is symptomatic of our issue or if it actually is the issue.

The official documentation is not entirely clear for this method as it says that the method calculates the "Cost of map & near cache & backup todo in object mode object size is zero."
I'm at a loss as to how to to interpret a negative value, and to be honest, with this kind of description it's not completely clear to me what a positive value is.